# What steps to take when a classmate of my 33-month-old bites him?

Tags: toddler, daycare, biting

My son is 2 years 9 months old. He has a classmate of roughly the same age. The class is for kids under 3 and over 2.

That classmate bites or attempts to bite my son. My son is his only target in class for some reason. He does this when the teacher is not around. My son doesn't bite back or complain to the teacher. There are bite marks on his hand, which I have shown to the teacher. The teacher said that this behavior was common among children of that age. The only defense my son has is a weak attempt to push the other kid away from him. So far this has happened 3 times.

Since this is happening in preschool, what steps should I take?

Comment: You say your son is in preschool, but in this case it might help to know even more specifically what his and the offender's exact ages are. I think the answers might vary significantly from 3 to 5. The problem needs to be addressed either way, but probably has different solutions.

Comment: I'd think it's not that unusual at that age. Maybe the best option would be to talk about it with the kid and his parents, but I suspect that at this age it's more like a nursery and you don't really know who the parents of the kid are. You may want to ask the teacher if he/she can arrange a meeting with them.

Comment: Make sure the biter has all of his shots. If the biter breaks skin, s/he could transmit blood diseases to your son.

Answer (score 1):

Teach your child to protest loudly. A loud *"no! don't bite me!"* should be enough, and if it isn't, it should get the teacher's attention.

Pushing away is also good, but why is he only doing it "weakly"?

What did the teacher say when you addressed this?

Comment: The teacher said - this behavior is common among children of that age. We are working with the other kid's parents to keep his behavior in check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a common behaviour for kids 3 years old. I have a son 2 and half and they passed that days way back ago. I would recommend the following steps:

1. Ask the teacher to speak to the kid's parents;
2. Bring awareness to the centre director, it is unsafe behaviour;
3. Teach your son to firmly say: "Stop! I don't like it!" with his hand near the chest and palm out.